# create new column based on values on previous rows

Tags: r

I hope somebody can help me.

```
I have a data like this:             
subject        choice  
 1               3  
 2               3    
 3               1    
 4               4    
 5               3    
 6               2    
 7               2    
 8               3
```

now I want to create a new column based on the value of 'choice' column. If the value on choice column is new (has never occurred  before), the value on the new column will be 'No', otherwise, if the value has already occur on previous rows , than the value in new column will be 'Soc'. the new table will look like this:

```
 subject        choice    newcolumn
   1               3           No
   2               3           Soc
   3               1           No
   4               4           No
   5               3           Soc
   6               2           No
   7               2           Soc
   8               3           Soc
```

can somebody help me? thanks in advance

Comment: look at `?duplicated`

Comment: possible duplicate of [create new column based on values on other two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812946/create-new-column-based-on-values-on-other-two-columns)

Answer (score 4):

Using example data

```
DF <- data.frame(subject = 1:8, choice = c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3))
```

I would do

```
DF <- transform(DF, newcolumn = c("No","Soc")[duplicated(choice) + 1])
```

giving

```
  subject choice newcolumn
1       1      3        No
2       2      3       Soc
3       3      1        No
4       4      4        No
5       5      3       Soc
6       6      2        No
7       7      2       Soc
8       8      3       Soc
```

Without `transform()` this would be

```
DF$newcolumn <- c("No","Soc")[duplicated(DF$choice) + 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `duplicated` and `ifelse`:

```
transform(DF, newcolumn = ifelse(!duplicated(choice),'No','Soc'))

##   subject choice newcolumn
## 1       1      3        No
## 2       2      3       Soc
## 3       3      1        No
## 4       4      4        No
## 5       5      3       Soc
## 6       6      2        No
## 7       7      2       Soc
## 8       8      3       Soc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but using bracket subsetting will teach you some useful things about R:

```
# Make your example reproducible
subject <- 1:8
choice <- c(3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3)
d <- data.frame(subject, choice)

# Create a new column, set all teh values to "No
d$newColumn <- "No"
# Set those values for which choice is duplicated to "Soc"
d$newColumn[duplicated(d$choice)] <- "Soc"
```